# How can I use AWS load balancer to check IP changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an instance running on premise and its IP address is changed regularly. My other services are running on AWS and they are using IP to connect to the premise's services. I have to update the IP address saved on AWS services whenever the IP is changed on premise network. I have a thought about using DNS but it is still a need to update A record.

I am looking for a way to do some auto-detect instead of manual updating. I wonder whether I can use load balancer to do the check. I know there will be a range of IP addresses on premise network. Can load balancer do a health check on these IP within the range? So my AWS service can send request to the load balancer. Is there any side-effect on this approach?

Comment: *"Can load balancer do a health check on these IP within the range?"*  This does not make sense to me.  How would anything scanning a range of addresses know whether the machine it found was indeed the correct machine? (Not a test build, clone, impostor, etc.?)  It sounds like you need to fix the root of the problem -- this machine needs a fixed address, perhaps something. as simple as a DHCP reservation, where it still "can" change but it does not.  Dynamic addresses don't really belong in production without DNS that's integrated with the infra for automatic updates.

Comment: In the target group setting of AWS, I can select IP address. I don't want to do much extra checking. A ping command is good enough for me

Comment: As Michael said, your proposed solution is not a good idea. As an alternative I would suggest creating a bash script on your on-premise server that uses the AWS cli to update a internal Route53 DNS record for your server. You can have the bash run on startup of the on premise server using cron. Then your aws servers all make use of the internal route53 dns record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hostname instead of IP address as you mentoned the IP addresses keeps changing. AWS VPC can use a DNS forwarder like Unbound, which can forward the requests to your on premise DNS server when VPC resolution is unable to resolve the hostnames. This appraoch is quite effective as you send only those DN resolution to on-premise DNS that are missed by AWS VPC DNS.

> [Unbound](https://www.unbound.net/) allows resolution of requests originating from AWS by
>   forwarding them to your on-premises environment—and vice versa. For
>   the purposes of this post, I will focus on a basic installation of
>   Amazon Linux with the configuration necessary to direct traffic to
>   on-premises environments or to the Amazon VPC–provided DNS, as
>   appropriate. Review the Unbound documentation for details and other
>   configuration options.

[image]

Further reading : [How to setup DNS resolution from AWS to on premise servers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-dns-resolution-between-on-premises-networks-and-aws-by-using-unbound/)

Comment: I believe the question might be about an on-premise machine that's serving as a target to an ALB, which works, with VPN or Direct Connect, but does not support DNS lookups of the target -- it's IP-only... but it isn't clear.